# What can I do to find the cause of pread64/pwrite64 hangs?

Tags: linux, io, profiling

My application is doing some heavy IO on raw /dev/sdb block device using pread64/pwrite64. Sometimes it doing just fine. Call to pread64/pwrite64 usually takes as little as 50-100us. But sometimes it takes a whole lot more, up to several seconds.

What can you recommend to find the cause of such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it but I have heard about a tool called latencytop.

Comment: latencytop is not useful for my case. I already know what particular operations are causing hangs. But I want to know the cause of such hangs. But thank you anyway for mentioning such a tool. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @Sergej: If you dig deeper into it, it looks like the kernel support for latencytop stores a full backtrace, not just the system call. With that you should be able to see what kernel functions were called during the slow pread64.

Comment: How to do that? I haven't found any info on it.

Answer (score 0):

When it's hung like that, grab a [stackshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). Another option is *pstack* or *lsstack*.
And as @Zan pointed out, *latencytop* could also give you that information.

That might not fully answer your question, but at least you'll know with certainty what it was trying to do when it was hung.